# ASP.NET - Can you make a DetailsView where only users with specific roles see some fields as editable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, webforms

For example lets say I want only admins to be able to see and edit CustomerID in details view, moderators can see this value but it is not editable, and regular users cannot even see it.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Now go google and come back when you have a more specific problem.

Comment: surely you can do anything, how are you handling roles right now? in short surely in the item data bound event you could hide or show or bind controls depending on current user's roles set

Comment: I performed a google search on this a while back. I had to piece multiple results from all my searches to get an answer as I was performing custom binding instead of using the conventional DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. I tried many google searches and no one could clearly explain it. You have to perform this on the PreRender Event. Please not that this code snippet uses the Membership Provider in .net to check if a user is in a role. If you have your own custom tables you will have to write a custom function that checks if a user is in one of your custom roles. Also please not that this solution is using `ItemTemplates` not BoundFields.

```
protected void detailsView_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dvPackage.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
        {
           //disables/enables a the dropdown for Process Status if the user has the RLIST role
           TextBox txtCustomID = (TextBox)Utilities.FindControlRecursive(dvPackage, "txtCustomID ");
           txtCustomID.Visible = false;
           if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
           {
              txtCustomID.Visible = true;

         }
     }
```

Here's the find control recursive funciton. Free of charge.

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control ctlRoot, string sControlId)
    {
        // if this control is the one we are looking for, break from the recursion    
        // and return the control.    
        if (ctlRoot.ID == sControlId)
        {
            return ctlRoot;
        }
        // loop the child controls of this parent control and call recursively.    
        foreach (Control ctl in ctlRoot.Controls)
        {
            Control ctlFound = FindControlRecursive(ctl, sControlId);
            // if we found the control, return it.        
            if (ctlFound != null)
            {
                return ctlFound;
            }
        }// we never found the control so just return null.    
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Small optimization:  Make the default of txtCustomID to be visible = false.  Then, you only have to do the recursive find if the user is an admin.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either web user controls or the multi-view to handle switching views based on the user's role.